# Try/catch Save Error Object to file not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a try catch loop and when I get an error I want to save it as a json file. However, the file comes back as an empty object.

```
try{
    //some error
} catch(e){
    fs.writeFileSync('err.json', JSON.stringify(e, null, 2), err=>{if(err)console.log(err)}) /// => {}
}
```

I can console.log the error and it will print just fine. There doesn't seem to be anything about this on duckduckgo so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: Yes, errors are often not `JSON.stringify`able (due to non-enumerable properties and whatnot). Try using [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) instead.

Comment: Btw, `writeFileSync` does not take a callback.

Comment: @pushkin I've never had an issue with putting a callback there before. Unless there was some kind of update within the last 12 hours this should be fine. I just tested it in another file and it worked perfect.

Comment: @Bergi thanks you just saved me a lot of future typing. It didn't break anything other than my fingers though.

Comment: @Bergi util.inspect(e) did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(new Error("message"))
```

You get:

```
message: {value: "message", writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
stack: {value: "Error: message↵    at <anonymous>:1:34", writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

Both of these properties are non-enumerable, so they won't show up when you use `JSON.stringify`. But fret not, you only really need the `.stack` property as that is a string containing:

- the error name,
- the error message, and
- the stack trace.

Because it is a string, you can just append the string directly to the log file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
try {
    throw new Error('error');
} catch(error) {
    fs.writeFileSync('err.json', error.stack + '\n', { flag: 'a' });
}
```

That should write something like the following to the target file:

```
Error: error
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path\to\file\test.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
var util = require('util')

try{
     //some error
} catch(e){
    fs.writeFileSync('err.json', util.inspect(e)) // => the error
}
```